# Add meta data to a Drupal page that isn't in the CMS?

Tags: drupal, metatag

I'm new to Drupal and I'm having to work on a site coded by another developer.

We have found and installed the Metatag module in order to give us access to change metadata on content inside the CMS. This is great for most things, however there are some types of content (not sure the exact Drupal terminology here) such as Testimonials and Case Studies. Each individual testimonial and case study has their own area in the CMS to edit the content, and these each have the Metatag module area to give us control over the metadata.

These types of content also have 'index pages' on the front-end (e.g. website.com/testimonials which lists all testimonials). Does anyone have any ideas as to where I can edit the metadata for these pages?

They're not in the CMS as classic pages and there seems to be nowhere to use the Metatag module to edit the metadata.

Either being able to update the metadata in the CMS or just hard-editing the template files would be an acceptable option.

Comment: If the other developer has done things the 'Drupal' way those pages will probably be views - if you enable the Metatag: Views module (bundled with metatag), then edit the the appropriate views, you'll see a link to provide meta tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These index pages can be created with various methods. It’s likely that they are created by the [**Views** module](https://drupal.org/project/views) or with the **Taxonomy** core module.

According to its description, the [**Metatag** module](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) seems to be capable of providing metatags for Views pages:

> Customize meta tags for custom pages built using Panels and Views using included submodules.

With the [**Metatag Views Overview** module](https://drupal.org/project/metatag_views_overview) it’s possible to edit the metatags for Views pages on Metatags’s overview page.

---

If nothing else works, it seems to be possible to provide metatags based on paths:

> Customize meta tags for specific paths (or other conditions) using [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) and included Metatag:Context submodule.

Comment: Fantastic, used the Views module and got it all working. Strange that when I go to Structure > Views > Services I don't see anything on that page, but when I go to the front-end and click the little cog icon and click 'Edit View' I get pretty much an identical page except I do see the metadata area. Oh well, thanks for your help :)