# Meta tags, Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, meta-tags

I want to add meta tags(title,keyword,description) on each page, views and blocks in drupal 7,  i have tried with two modules meta tags quick and meta tags but they are not giving the permission to add meta tags on views and blocks, it only gives the permission to add meta tags on pages.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add meta data to a Drupal page that isn't in the CMS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788975/add-meta-data-to-a-drupal-page-that-isnt-in-the-cms)

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags quick allows you to define path based meta tags, so if you're using clean urls shouldn't be too big of a problem unless the urls are often changed.
https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick

Alternatively you could create all your pages as node and add the views as blocks to those node pages.