# How to add meta tags to pages with generated content in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, metadata, drupal-modules, meta-tags

I'm optimizing site on Drupal. This is my first experience with this CMS, so I'm a total noob with it.

Problem is how to edit meta tags (title and meta description) on pages with generated content (e.g. news)?

On regular pages I've used Meta Tags module and it works just fine. But I cannot access pages that generate content like news, events etc., these pages are not listed in the Content section.

Is there a relatively simple way (via UI) to edit meta tags for these kind of pages?

Current Drupal version is 7.38

Hopefully I've provided enough information for this issue and described in a clear understandable way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add meta data to a Drupal page that isn't in the CMS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788975/add-meta-data-to-a-drupal-page-that-isnt-in-the-cms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "generated pages" are view pages. Try finding some module that adds meta tags to view pages, i.e.:

https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick

or maybe

https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag_views_overview

Comment: Thanks, Meta tags Quick module, works fine for me. Also thanks for clarifying that these pages are called 'View' pages. Now the only problem left is how to assign meta tags for View pages for each language on my website. Sorry I didn't mention that in the first place.